# loading dataset data to DropDownList c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, dropdown, dropdownlistfor

i have this dropdownlist in my popup function that does not load the data i want, i have breakpointed and confirmed that i get the data i want, but for some reason, the dropdownlist is still empty.

C#:

```
protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var nodes = _administrationSystem.GetNodes(); //The dataset with data
    var translators = _phonesSystem.GetPhoneNumberTranslators(); //The dataset with data

    if (rptList.Items.Count > 0)
    {
        for (var count = 0; count < rptList.Items.Count; count++)
        {
            var ddlNodeEdit = (DropDownList)rptList.Items[count].FindControl("ddlNodeEdit");
            var ddlTranslatorEdit = (DropDownList)rptList.Items[count].FindControl("ddlTranslatorEdit");

            ddlNodeEdit.DataSource = nodes;
            ddlNodeEdit.DataTextField = "NodeName";
            ddlNodeEdit.DataValueField = "ID";
            ddlNodeEdit.DataBind();
            ddlNodeEdit.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("TRNSLTChoose node", "0"));

            ddlTranslatorEdit.DataSource = translators;
            ddlTranslatorEdit.DataTextField = "Description";
            ddlTranslatorEdit.DataValueField = "ID";
            ddlTranslatorEdit.DataBind();
            ddlTranslatorEdit.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("TRNSLTChoose numbertranslator", "0"));
        }
    }
}
```

ASPX:

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" OnItemCommand="rptList_OnItemCommand" ID="rptList">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <table class="tblRegister">
            <tr class="tblRowHeader" style="background-color: rgb(200,200,200)">
                <th>
                    <asp:Label runat="server" Text="TRNSLTFirstname" />
                </th>
                <th>
                    <asp:Label runat="server" Text="TRNSLTSurname" />
                </th>
                <th>
                    <asp:Label runat="server" Text="TRNSLTNode index" />
                </th>
                <th>
                    <asp:Label runat="server" Text="TRNSLTNumber translation" />
                </th>
                <th>
                    <asp:Label runat="server" Text="TRNSLTEmail" />
                </th>
                <th colspan="3">
                    <asp:Label runat="server" Text="TRNSLTLast login" />
                </th>
            </tr>
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <%# OperatorId.HasValue && OperatorId == Convert.ToInt32(Eval("ID"))? "<tr style='background-color: #94C5E1;'>" : "<tr>" %>
                <td>
                    <%# Eval("FirstName") %>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <%# Eval("SurName") %>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <%# Eval("NodeIndex") %>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <%# Eval("TranslatorName") %>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <%# Eval("EMail") %>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <%# Eval("LastLogin") %>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:LinkButton ToolTip="TRNSLTDelete" ID="btnDelete" CssClass="deleteOperator" runat="server" CommandName="deleteBtn" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID") %>' OnClientClick="return OpenPopup(this)">
                        <asp:Image ImageUrl="Images/Icons/Deleted-16x16.png" ID="DeleteVisitor" runat="server" />
                    </asp:LinkButton>
                    <div id="myModal" class="modal">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <h3 class="modalHdr">
                                <asp:Label runat="server" Text="TRNSLTRemove users" />
                            </h3>
                            <asp:LinkButton ToolTip="TRNSLTNo" CommandName="noBtn" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID") %>' ID="ButtonNo" runat="server" Text="TRNSLTNo" CssClass="popupConfirm" />
                            <asp:LinkButton ToolTip="TRNSLTYes" CommandName="yesBtn" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID") %>' ID="ButtonYes" runat="server" Text="TRNSLTYes" CssClass="popupConfirm" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:LinkButton CommandName="selectBtn" ToolTip="TRNSLTEdit" ID="btnEdit" CssClass="editOperator" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID")%>' OnClientClick="return PopupEdit(this)">
                        <asp:Image ImageUrl="Images/Icons/Edit-16x16.png" ID="EditVisitor" runat="server" />
                    </asp:LinkButton>
                    <div id="modalEdit" class="modal">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <p style="margin-left: 50px;">
                                <img src="Images/Icons/Sip.png" alt="" />
                                <%# Eval("FirstName") %> <%# Eval("SurName") %>
                            </p>
                            <br />
                            <asp:DropDownList CssClass="ddlNodeClass" runat="server" ID="ddlNodeEdit" />
                            <asp:DropDownList CssClass="ddlTranslatorClass" runat="server" ID="ddlTranslatorEdit" />
                            <asp:LinkButton ToolTip="TRNSLTCancel" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID") %>' ID="btnNo" runat="server" CssClass="btnCancelClass" OnClientClick="return Cancel(this)">
                                <asp:Image ImageUrl="Images/Icons/Cancel-22x22.png" ID="SaveContact" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />
                            </asp:LinkButton>
                            <asp:LinkButton ToolTip="TRNSLTSave" CommandName="submitBtn" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID") %>' ID="btnYes" runat="server" CssClass="btnSaveClass">
                                <asp:Image ImageUrl="Images/Icons/Check-22x22.png" ID="SaveOperator" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />
                            </asp:LinkButton>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
        </table>
            </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: Yeah that did not help. I tried `AutoPostBack="True"`, still nothing.

Comment: Did you try doing it in page_load event ?

Comment: Yes I did, does not work either.

Comment: Did you get the control inside the loop ?

Comment: Yes everything in code behind is ok.

Comment: have you put this dropdownlist inside an UpdatePanel?

Comment: No, I have not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        var nodes = _administrationSystem.GetNodes(); //The dataset with data
        var translators = _phonesSystem.GetPhoneNumberTranslators(); //The dataset with data

        if (rptList.Items.Count > 0)
        {
            for (var count = 0; count < rptList.Items.Count; count++)
            {
                var ddlNodeEdit = (DropDownList)rptList.Items[count].FindControl("ddlNodeEdit");
                var ddlTranslatorEdit = (DropDownList)rptList.Items[count].FindControl("ddlTranslatorEdit");

                ddlNodeEdit.DataSource = nodes.Tables[0];
                ddlNodeEdit.DataTextField = "NodeName";
                ddlNodeEdit.DataValueField = "ID";
                ddlNodeEdit.DataBind();
                ddlNodeEdit.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("TRNSLTChoose node", "0"));

                ddlTranslatorEdit.DataSource = translators.Tables[0];
                ddlTranslatorEdit.DataTextField = "Description";
                ddlTranslatorEdit.DataValueField = "ID";
                ddlTranslatorEdit.DataBind();
                ddlTranslatorEdit.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("TRNSLTChoose numbertranslator", "0"));
            }
        }
}
```

And `.aspx` page as

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">        
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Repeater runat="server" OnItemCommand="rptList_OnItemCommand" ID="rptList">
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <table class="tblRegister">
                    <tr class="tblRowHeader" style="background-color: rgb(200,200,200)">
                        <th>
                            <asp:Label runat="server" Text="TRNSLTFirstname" />
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            <asp:Label runat="server" Text="TRNSLTSurname" />
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            <asp:Label runat="server" Text="TRNSLTNode index" />
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            <asp:Label runat="server" Text="TRNSLTNumber translation" />
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            <asp:Label runat="server" Text="TRNSLTEmail" />
                        </th>
                        <th colspan="3">
                            <asp:Label runat="server" Text="TRNSLTLast login" />
                        </th>
                    </tr>
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%# OperatorId.HasValue && OperatorId == Convert.ToInt32(Eval("ID"))? "<tr style='background-color: #94C5E1;'>" : "<tr>" %>
                <td>
                    <%# Eval("FirstName") %>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <%# Eval("SurName") %>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <%# Eval("NodeIndex") %>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <%# Eval("TranslatorName") %>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <%# Eval("EMail") %>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <%# Eval("LastLogin") %>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:LinkButton ToolTip="TRNSLTDelete" ID="btnDelete" CssClass="deleteOperator" runat="server" CommandName="deleteBtn" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID") %>' OnClientClick="return OpenPopup(this)">
                        <asp:Image ImageUrl="Images/Icons/Deleted-16x16.png" ID="DeleteVisitor" runat="server" />
                    </asp:LinkButton>

                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:LinkButton CommandName="selectBtn" ToolTip="TRNSLTEdit" ID="btnEdit" CssClass="editOperator" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID")%>' OnClientClick="return PopupEdit(this)">
                        <asp:Image ImageUrl="Images/Icons/Edit-16x16.png" ID="EditVisitor" runat="server" />
                    </asp:LinkButton>

                </td>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                </table>
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>     
  </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
                    <div id="modalEdit" class="modal">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <p style="margin-left: 50px;">
                                <img src="Images/Icons/Sip.png" alt="" />
                                <%# Eval("FirstName") %> <%# Eval("SurName") %>
                            </p>
                            <br />
                            <asp:DropDownList CssClass="ddlNodeClass" runat="server" ID="ddlNodeEdit" />
                            <asp:DropDownList CssClass="ddlTranslatorClass" runat="server" ID="ddlTranslatorEdit" />
                            <asp:LinkButton ToolTip="TRNSLTCancel" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID") %>' ID="btnNo" runat="server" CssClass="btnCancelClass" OnClientClick="return Cancel(this)">
                                <asp:Image ImageUrl="Images/Icons/Cancel-22x22.png" ID="SaveContact" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />
                            </asp:LinkButton>
                            <asp:LinkButton ToolTip="TRNSLTSave" CommandName="submitBtn" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID") %>' ID="btnYes" runat="server" CssClass="btnSaveClass">
                                <asp:Image ImageUrl="Images/Icons/Check-22x22.png" ID="SaveOperator" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />
                            </asp:LinkButton>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div id="myModal" class="modal">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <h3 class="modalHdr">
                                <asp:Label runat="server" Text="TRNSLTRemove users" />
                            </h3>
                            <asp:LinkButton ToolTip="TRNSLTNo" CommandName="noBtn" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID") %>' ID="ButtonNo" runat="server" Text="TRNSLTNo" CssClass="popupConfirm" />
                            <asp:LinkButton ToolTip="TRNSLTYes" CommandName="yesBtn" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID") %>' ID="ButtonYes" runat="server" Text="TRNSLTYes" CssClass="popupConfirm" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: After databind() event code, check the items count for given Drop Down List

Comment: Yeah, I get the correct count. 4 for ddlNode and 14 for ddlTranslator.

Comment: I think you will have to remove that modal from there , you should use Update Panel and place a repeater control inside Update Panel , as well keep all modal outside Update Panel

Comment: I cannot remove the modal, my design needs to have that popup.

Comment: you don't need to remove it, you need to keep it out side of an Update Panel and keep Repeater Control inside the Update Panel

Comment: Could you please create a post with the code and show me how you mean?